# Flutter google_sign_in missing refresh token

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am trying to get the refresh token from the flutter package "google_sign_in" to backend to process data whenever necessary. However, I am not 100% sure if the package is currently not supporting it or there is other way to retrieve it.

I have tried to search for answers but came to no avail.